# Objective-Cの、unarchivedObjectOfClassがnilを返す

Tags: objective-c

お世話になります。初めて投稿します。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Objective-Cで、以下のメソッドが廃止されたので、

```
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:(NSString *)path];
```

書き換えをしました。

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
array = (NSArray*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:[NSArray class] fromData:data error:&error];
```

dataには、NSDataのデータが入っていますが、NSArrayのarrayはnilになります。
何か書き方が悪いのでしょうか？

もしご存知の方がいれば、ご教授ください。

ご教授ありがとうございます。投稿していただいたコードで修正したところ、こちらもご指摘通りNSSecureCodingに適合していないというエラーが出ました。

```
"This decoder will only decode classes that adopt NSSecureCoding. Class 'FileItem' does not adopt it."
```

```
@interface FileItem : NSObject <NSCoding>
```

を、

```
@interface FileItem : NSObject <NSSecureCoding>
```

に書き換えて、

```
+ (BOOL)supportsSecureCoding
{
    return YES;
}
```

も追加してみましたが、以下のエラーが出ます

```
2020-04-13 23:46:36.348044+0900 MosaicMaker[21527:3134349] Error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "value for key 'identifier' was of unexpected class 'NSMutableString'. Allowed classes are '{(
    NSArray,
    FileItem
)}'." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=value for key 'identifier' was of unexpected class 'NSMutableString'. Allowed classes are '{(
    NSArray,
    FileItem
)}'.}
```

どう修正すればいいのか、簡単にお分かりのようでしたら教えていただくことは
できますでしょうか？厚かましいお願いで申し訳ありませんが、よろしくお願いいたします。

FileItemの全体は、以下になります。

```
@interface FileItem : NSObject <NSSecureCoding /*NSCoding*/>
{
    NSString*   _identifier;        // 識別子
    BOOL        _selected;          // 選択フラグ
    NSString*   _title;             // タイトル
    NSString*   _makeDate;          // 作成された日付
    NSString*   _size;              // ファイルサイズ(mm x mm)
}
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

解決できました。
ご教授いただいたように、/*...*/にアーカイブするクラスを書いたところ、問題なく解凍できました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: `unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error:`が`nil`を返す場合、`error`にはなんらかのエラーオブジェクトが設定されているはずです。何が入っていますか?

Comment: NSLog(@"Error %@", [error description]);
で表示したところ、以下のように出ました。

2020-04-13 00:52:41.375986+0900 MosaicMaker[20928:3001684] Error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "value for key 'NS.objects' was of unexpected class 'FileItem'. Allowed classes are '{(
    NSArray
)}'." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=value for key 'NS.objects' was of unexpected class 'FileItem'. Allowed classes are '{(
    NSArray
)}'.}

Comment: すいません。ありがとうございます。
NSArray*    files;
     files = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:filePath];
を以下のように書き換えています。上記はうまくいっています。
NSError *error = nil;
     NSData *newData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
     files = (NSArray*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:[NSArray class] fromData:newData error:&error];

     NSLog(@"Error %@", [error description]);

Comment: 情報のご提示ありがとうございます。ほぼ状況はわかりました。回答を考えるにあたって、極めて重要な情報ですので、本文を編集して、本文中に記載していただいた方が良いでしょう。なお、質問本文中にコードを入れる場合には、```だけの行を最初と最後に記入してやると、記号も含めてコードとして整形されて表示されます。プレビューでどんな表示になるかは確かめられますから、是非その部分の編集と、その後にエラー情報の追記をお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error:`や`unarchivedObjectOfClasses:fromData:error:`は、本来は`NSSecureCoding`をサポートするためのメソッドで、アーカイブの中に含まれる全てのクラスを`unarchivedObjectOfClass:`または`unarchivedObjectOfClasses:`に渡してやらないといけません。

あなたは、`NSArray`だけを渡していますが、アーカイブの中に`FileItem`と言う名前のクラスが含まれているのに、それが示されていないので実行時エラーになります。両方のクラスを渡してやらないといけません。

```
        NSArray *array = (NSArray *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver
                                     unarchivedObjectOfClasses:[NSSet setWithObjects:
                                        [NSArray class], [FileItem class], /*...,*/
                                      nil]
                                     fromData:data error:&error];
```

- 他のクラスでアーカイブの中に含まれているものがあれば...のところに指定してください。
- `FileItem`が`NSSecureCoding`(ただの`NSCoding`ではなく)に適合していないと、別のエラーになるかもしれません。その場合には、`FileItem`が`NSSecureCoding`に適合するように修正してください。

Comment: ＠OOPer様、本文を修正しました。何もわからず見にくいコメントをつけてしまってすいませんでした。

Comment: @岡田茂 さん、なぜ`FileItem`全体をご質問に掲載されないのでしょうか? 回答に示したコードの中に`/*...,*/`と言うのがあるのと、「他のクラスでアーカイブの中に含まれているものがあれば...のところに指定してください」と書いたのはきちんと読んでいただいたのでしょうか?

Comment: ＠OOPer様
回答は読ませていただきましたが、Primitive型は問題ないと思い書いていませんでした。すいませんでした。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @岡田茂 さん、Objective-Cで「Primitive型」と言うのは`int`や`char`のような数値型だけと言うことになりますし、そもそもどこにも「Primitive型は問題ない」なんて記述はドキュメントにありません。(私が試したところ`NSString`は指定しなくても動くようですが、それは「Primitive型」だからではなく、「`NSKeyedUnarchiver`がそう作られているから」です。)とにかく`unexpected class '〜'`なんて実行時エラーが出たら、片っ端から`/*...,*/`のところに付け加えてみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございました。ベストアンサーにチェックしました。
大変助かりました。